# SQL still got duplicate rows after add DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

Here is SQL include three tables,**trans**,**sys_org** and **sys_pay**.select through **mid** (but it is not unique)

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT trans.mid,trans.A,sys_org.B,sys_org.C,sys_pay.D 
    FROM sys_org  
    LEFT JOIN trans ON sys_org.mid = trans.mid 
    LEFT JOIN sys_pay ON sys_org.mid = sys_pay.mid
```

and it returns duplicate rows,how to fix it?

return like this:

```
trans.mid  trans.A  sys_org.B  sys_org.C  sys_pay.D
1111       aaa      bbb        ccc        ddd
1111       aaa      bbb        ccc        ddd
```

Comment: What is your notion of "duplicate" rows?  Can you show us some sample output?

Comment: Can you provide a real example, with proper CREATE and INSERT statements

Comment: @Strawberry You're a bit late to the party.  Both `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are giving him the result set above.  I suspect that something is funky with his data.

Comment: You are right,something wrong with my data.Thanks to point it out.

Answer (score -2):

I am sure that your all rows will be distinct but here distinct means whole row not any specific column.

If it is not then create a sqlfiddle so that I can check it.

Further if you want to fetch unique value based on specific field then you should use group by.

Comment: Either there is any space or junk character in your data of any field. If you create sqlfiddle here then we can check it. link is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Well, it's not really an answer is it, more of a comment